# asp:Chart control. Can not set starting date value for X-Axis

Tags: c#, asp.net, html, charts, data-visualization

I have a Chart control with a line series on it. I pass a data table with 4 rows to it containing a decimal value and a date each. The dates range from 4 September - 7 September. When the graph is generated, the starting value of the X-Axis is 3 September causing the graph to have a blank spot at the start. How can I make the X-Axis start at 4 September? I'm able to set the y-Axis start value because the `Chart1.ChartAreas[0].AxisY.Minimum` property expects a double value.

Comment: How about setting the Minimum x Value using the `ToOADate` of the least date you have !

Comment: Thanks V4Vendetta, that worked!